# How to find the number of ring homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}^3$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I just find that there are 8 ring homomorphisms including trivial homomorphism but I'm not sure
8 ring homomorphism are as follows:
$F(1)=(1,0,0)$
$F(1)=(0,1,0)$
$F(1)=(0,0,1)$
$F(1)=(1,1,0)$
$F(1)=(0,1,1)$
$F(1)=(1,0,1)$
$F(1)=(1,1,1)$
$F(1)=(0,0,0)$

Comment: Could you please use LaTeX to formulate your questions

Comment: welcome to math exchange, please go through a tutorial for asking a question

Answer (score 1):

If you assume $f:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ are unital ring homomorphism, then there is obviously only one ring homomorphism.

If you work in the category of non-unital rings then there are $8$. To see this look at $f(1) = x = (x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $f(1\cdot 1) = f(1)^2 = f(1)$. In this case $x^2 = x$ which implies $x_i\in \{-1,0,1\}$. Can one of $x_i$ be negative?